# Flutter : cannot play video from the network

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I use video_player package to show video, but it's not working when I set to play video on the network.

```
     String url =
      'https://www.tiktok.com/@longtho11/video/7108968034764721435?is_from_webapp=1&sender_device=pc&web_id=6992499779570419202';
  String url2 =
      'http://www.tiktok.com/@annhien_boiboi/video/7109312398330203418?is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1';
  String url3 = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
  bool isMute = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(url3)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..setLooping(true)
      ..initialize().then((value) => videoController.play());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: VideoPlayerCustom(videoController: videoController),
      ),
    );
```

What did I wrong? Help me

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have internet permission inside android manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The manifest file will be here : `projectdirectory/android/app/src/main`

It will be like this : [image]

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Comment: First 2 url will not work as its banned here and third one is working